# I want my jQueryUI range slider to move dynamically depending on the input value

Tags: html, jquery-ui, rangeslider

[here is the range slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2d8m.png)

Basically I want my slider to move when i change the number inside the input.

HTML Code:

```
<input id="txtMinPrice" type="text" placeholder="de la">
<input id="txtMaxPrice" type="text" placeholder="pana la">
<div id="price__range"></div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
`var sliderElement = $('#price__range');
$("#price__range").slider({
  range: true,
  min: 0,
  max: 100,
  values: [ 35, 100 ],
  slide: function(event, ui) {
    $('#txtMinPrice').val(ui.values[0]);
    $('#txtMaxPrice').val(ui.values[1]);
  }
});
$('#txtMinPrice').val(sliderElement.slider('values', 0));
$('#txtMaxPrice').val(sliderElement.slider('values', 1));`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#txtMinPrice, #txtMaxPrice').on({
    'input change': function(){
         $("#price__range").slider("option", "min", $('#txtMinPrice').val());
         $("#price__range").slider("option", "max", $('#txtMaxPrice').val());
         $('#price__range').slider( "option", "value", $('#price__range').slider("value"));
    }
})
```

Basically, you listen for either the `input` or the `change` event on the inputs, which you can modify as needed, and proceed to replace the min and max values of the slider. From the [docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-range).

Comment: didn't throw any error, just when i put any number in the input, both slider circles move to the left, and after that they don't move

Comment: My bad, I forgot to update the value. I've updated the code. It should work now.

Comment: still the same problem :\